# Proving $|Z| \leq \binom{n}{l}/ \binom{m}{l}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

> Let $l \leq m $.  Let $X$ be a set $|X| = n$ and $Z \subseteq \binom{X}{m}$, so that for every set $L \in \binom{X}{l}$ there is at most one set $B \in Z$  with $L \subseteq B$. How can one prove the following:
>   $$|Z| \leq \frac{\binom{n}{l}}{\binom{m}{l}}\,?$$

**I did the following and I'd like to know if it is correct or not.**

$$\binom{n}{l} =\frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!} $$
and

$$\binom{m}{l} =\frac{m!}{l!(m-l)!}\,.$$

Dividing both:

$$\frac{\frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}}{\frac{m!}{l!(m-l)!}} = \frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!} \cdot \frac {l!(m-l)!}{m!}\,. $$

Since $Z \subseteq \binom{X}{m}$, we can say that
$$Z \subseteq \frac{X!}{m!(X-m)!}\,,$$

so it follows that

$$\frac{X!}{m!(X-m)!} \leq \frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!} \cdot \frac {l!(m-l)!}{m!}\,. $$

We can divide by $$\frac {l!(m-l)!}{m!}$$

and get

$$\frac{X!}{m!(X-m)!} \cdot \frac {m!}{l!(m-l)!} \leq \frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}\,. $$

We can cancel $m!$ and get

$$\frac {|X|!}{(|X|-m)! \cdot l!(m-l)!} \leq \frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}\,.$$

Since $|X| = n$, we can write

$$\frac {n!}{(n-m)! \cdot l!(m-l)!} \leq \frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}\,,$$

which is true, because **the bigger the denominator gets, the smaller the number.**

Comment: While the notation $\displaystyle \binom{X}{m}$ makes sense, the expression $\dfrac{X!}{m!\, (X-m)!}$ does not make sense, since $X$ is a set, not a number, let alone comparing such an expression with a number.

Comment: Some of your notation is a bit strange.  What is $X!$ or $(X-m)!$?  Do you mean $|X|$?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean $|X|$, edited it

Comment: And the last inequality is wrong.  The inequality is equivalent to $$(n-l)!\leq (n-m)!\,(m-l)!\,,$$ which is identical to  $$\binom{n-l}{m-l}\leq 1\,.$$   This is false for large $n$, of course.  Therefore, I am sorry to say that your proof is incorrect.

Comment: Where is the inequality following the statement "So it follows that" coming from?  This makes the result appear circular.

Comment: I replaced $Z$ with $\binom{X}{m}$ since $Z \subseteq \binom{X}{m}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$S:=\Biggl\{(L,B)\in \binom{X}{l}\times Z\,\Big|\,L\subseteq B\Biggr\}.$$
Since for each $\displaystyle L\in \binom{X}{l}$, there exists at most one $B$ in $Z$ for which $L\subseteq B$, we have
$$|S|\leq \Biggl|\binom{X}{l}\Biggr|=\binom{n}{l}\,.$$
Now, each $B\in Z$ has $m$ elements, and therefore, there are $\displaystyle\binom{m}{l}$ subsets $\displaystyle L\in\binom{X}{l}$ such that $L\subseteq B$.  This shows that
$$|S|=\binom{m}{l}\,|Z|\,.$$
The claim follows immediately.